# ApplicationInsights customMetrics data not available for WebJob

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-application-insights

I'm using Azure function and WebJob in .Net and sending logs into ApplicationInsights using TelemetryClient.

I have almost same logging code for WebJob and Azure function.

For azure function, I can see my data in Requests, Traces and customMetrics but for WebJob no data is available in customMetrics only available in Traces and Requests.

My EventHub WebJob logging Code

```
public Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
    {
        foreach (var eventData in messages)
        {
            Log log = LogManager.GetLogger();
            RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry = new RequestTelemetry { Name = "EventhubWebJob" };
            requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("MessageId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
            IOperationHolder<RequestTelemetry> operation = log.TelemetryClient.StartOperation(requestTelemetry);
            operation.Telemetry.Success = true;
            log.Trace($"Message processing start...");
            try
            {
                log.Trace("Message received.");
                Console.WriteLine($"Message received.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                operation.Telemetry.Success = false;
                log.Trace(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                log.Trace($"Message processing completed.");
                log.TelemetryClient.StopOperation(operation);
            }

        }

        return context.CheckpointAsync();
    }
```

I can see below data for Function same I need for WebJob.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `ApplicationInsights` with WebJob, you need use the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights` nuget package even it's a beta currently.

You need three packages in total:

1. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights
2. Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
3. Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console

Configure the JobHostConfiguration

```
string instrumentationKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(instrumentationKey))
{
      // build up a LoggerFactory with ApplicationInsights and a Console Logger
       config.LoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory().AddApplicationInsights(instrumentationKey, null).AddConsole();
       config.Tracing.ConsoleLevel = TraceLevel.Off;
}
```

**Note**: Don't forget adding the `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` in your application setting.

About the `ILogger` filtering, you could refer to the [`Application Insights Integration`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Application-Insights-Integration#filtering) wiki, `CategoryLevels` allows you to specify log levels for specific categories so you can fine-tune the logging output.

And you could add the `LogError` with code:

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, ILogger logger)
    {
    //you can directly use this line of code.
    logger.LogError(new Exception(),"it is a test error...");
    }
```

**Update**:

[image]

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: I think you have mixed Function and WebJob code. Is it?

Comment: @Pankaj Rawat, this is webjob code and the link is about integrating webjo with  ApplicationInsights.

Comment: Let me try this

Comment: @Pankaj Rawat, and the ProcessQueueMessage is just a sample code I created in Function.cs within a webjob.

Comment: that is why, I was thinking is it function

Comment: @Pankaj Rawat, it's part of a webjob.

Comment: Just one confirmation, Are you able to see data in customMetrics?

Comment: @Pankaj Rawat,yes in the Live Metrics Stream, I could see the exception, I update the answer and paste the picture.

Comment: I appreciate your effort. But I need data in customMetrics. probably you can re-check my question. customMeterics will help me to setup performance reports.

Comment: @Pankaj Rawat, I checked , in the customMeterics it could be seen, I update the picture.

Comment: Thanks George Chen :)