# Monitoring Azure WebJob & Function App Failures

Tags: azure, azure-functions, webhooks, azure-webjobs, azure-function-app

I'm currently acting as the SharePoint admin for a company that has some code jobs (mix of WebJobs and Function Apps) running in the background of an O365 site, performing some misc tasks like ensuring the webhook sub is still active, cloning sites, and populating clones with info from a form in SharePoint.

These jobs are mission critical as they are linked to a crisis management site so I've been asked to put in some monitoring for assurance that we'll be alerted if any fail, either as part of a schedule or on-demand (again there is a mix of these).

The problem is I don't really understand much of Azure, other than it replaces the farm solutions in SP as a place to run back-end code, especially with the plethora of names for things that seem to me to be pretty similar.

Can anyone reccomend an easy way I can set up some sort of monitoring trigger for the individual webjobs and functions for a failure, ideally just using the built in Azure control panel (i.e. without having to deploy any code - I'm really not a C# and the like coder).

Comment: For azure function, you can easily use [application insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring) to monitor it. For webjobs, I think we should use some code of application insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both Function and webjob, you all could use Application Insight to monitor them.

For Function, Ivan has linked the official doc: [Monitor Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring), and for webjob official doc actually has a tutorial about configuring Application Insight:[Add Application Insights logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started#add-application-insights-logging).

Also you could refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55683129/10383250) about using application insight. Use this package:`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights` and add JobHostConfiguration.

```
    string instrumentationKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(instrumentationKey))
    {
          // build up a LoggerFactory with ApplicationInsights and a Console Logger
           config.LoggerFactory = new LoggerFactory().AddApplicationInsights(instrumentationKey, null).AddConsole();
           config.Tracing.ConsoleLevel = TraceLevel.Off;
    }
```

Then you will be able to add webjob logs. Hope this could help you.